# Is it possible to make a log in form, that saves its data after the program closes and reopens other than using SQL?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

I want to create a C# windows form application login form that allows the user to create an account and was hoping to save that account locally (in a file in current pc) for academic purposes. Different solutions that I have encountered have all suggested to use mySQL to save the file. Although it is very much effective, I am hoping to find an alternative solution.

I have already tried using mySQL but I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: "other than using SQL" Well, first define what an "account" actually is, and what you want to save from it. Do you just need your application to remember the account name that last logged in? Do you need to switch between multiple saved accounts? Are you "authenticating" their login using this saved account somehow? Etc...

Comment: If you don't actually want to use a full fledged RDBMS but stay close to it, I'd recommend a single file db. Examples being SQLite or the .net native nosql alternative LiteDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely just save the information locally.

The simplest option is to use a serialization library, like [system.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0). Just create an object to represent the data, and ask the library to serialize it to a file. You would typically store this file in a subfolder under [localapplicationData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=net-7.0), at least if it is managed by the application.

You can decide when to save/load the data:

1. The application starts/closes (with the risk of data loss if the application crashes)
2. When the user explicitly saves/loads the file
3. Whenever the data changes

My recommendation would be to start storing data in a file, since that is typically simpler than a database. But you might want to have an interface for the part that does the storage, so that the majority of your code don't have to care *how* it is stored. That should help you move to a database if your requirements grow.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about security, you can store the data in a XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<accounts>
  <account id="1">
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>admin123</password>
    <email>admin@example.com</email>
  </account>
  <account id="2">
    <username>demo</username>
    <password>demo123</password>
    <email>demo@example.com</email>
  </account>
</accounts>
```

Read more about XML here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=net-7.0